# Outsource geocoder location when writing a location based status

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I am currently able to write a status in my app that saves the fetched user location (html5 javascript -> geocoder) right into the status database, when writing a new status. Now I want to outsource the location into a new model and relate to it in my status model. Something like
Status Model: Content, Location_id....Location Model: Lat, Lng, Address. My problem is the form for saving the status. I will use two forms in one. One for the Status and in that another form for the location saving. How do i associate the right location_id to that specific status? Because the location_id is only generated AFTER saving the whole status.
Any ideas? Maybe some asynchronous stuff? I have really no clue how to solve this problem. I would really appreciate your help :)
Happy new year to all of you :D

Comment: So your problem is to create a record of a Location model that belongs to a Status model right after having created the Status record ?

Comment: Thats true location and Status model should be created at The same time if Status model does not already exist. Or maybe create The location model at page load an reference The Status to it, when created would ne a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your Status controller :

```
class StatusController < ApplicationController

  [..]

  def create
    @status = Status.new(params[:status])
    @location = Location.new(whatever parameters you want : nested params, or anything else)
    status = @status.save
    if status && @location.save
       redirect_to @status, notice: 'Sucessfully created.'
    elsif status
       @status.destroy
       redirect_to new_status_path, alert: 'Something went wrong with your location.'
    else
       redirect_to new_status_path, alert: 'Something went wrong'
    end

  end

  [..]

end
```